# WinForms RDLC Report Monthly Sale Report for all Salesman

Tags: winforms, rdlc

I am stuck with this report for more then 10 days, please help. My client have 50 Salesman, he want a Report which can show in header Salesman Name, Area, City and in Report Body his daily sale and in footer total sale, I tried all but not able to work it around. please help.

it must print all 50 Report.

Regards
Moksha

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table and group each row by the field "Salesman". After that you can specify that for the group "Salesman" each new "row group" must insert a page break.
In this way you should have a report with N page where N is the number of Salesman.

If you don't know how to do that I leave here some useful link: [table grouping](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207019.aspx) and p[age break for each row group](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207058.aspx) (last paragraph).

When you have grouped the first table, you can use antoher one table for the "report detail" following the master/detail idea. You can found more example [here](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/masterdetail/index.html) or [here](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/creating-a-master-detail-report-in-ssrs-without-using-sub-report/)